# Error: Cannot find module './options/SchemaTypeOptions'

Tags: node.js, mongoose

What this means?

I created a simple web app using NodeJs and deployed it to the Heroku. The built was successfully, but when I run the app it throws me this. In localhost worked well,

```
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:638
2019-11-02T19:50:40.185373+00:00 app[web.1]: throw err;
2019-11-02T19:50:40.185375+00:00 app[web.1]: ^
2019-11-02T19:50:40.185377+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2019-11-02T19:50:40.185379+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: Cannot find module './options/SchemaTypeOptions'
2019-11-02T19:50:40.185381+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:636:15)
2019-11-02T19:50:40.185382+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:562:25)
2019-11-02T19:50:40.185384+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:692:17)
2019-11-02T19:50:40.185385+00:00 app[web.1]: at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:25:18)
2019-11-02T19:50:40.185387+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/schematype.js:8:27)
2019-11-02T19:50:40.185388+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:30)
2019-11-02T19:50:40.185392+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)
2019-11-02T19:50:40.185393+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
2019-11-02T19:50:40.185395+00:00 app[web.1]: at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
2019-11-02T19:50:40.185396+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
```

I reinstalled the node_modules folder, but nothing..
Can you please help me out? Thank you in advance!

UPDATE

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const userSchema = new Schema({
name:{
    type:String,
    required:true
},
    password: {
        type:String,
        required:true
    }
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
```

This is the model where I use a Schema Object

```
const express = require('express');
const helmet = require('helmet');
const path = require('path');
const compression = require('compression');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const app = express();
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const flash = require('connect-flash');
const User = require('./models/user');
const session = require('express-session');
const MongoDBStore = require('connect-mongodb-session')(session);
const bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');
app.use(flash());
app.use(helmet());
app.use(compression());


app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.set('views', 'views');
const MONGODB_URI = `mongodb+srv://*******-xo7un.mongodb.net/247SharedKitchen`;

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
const store = new MongoDBStore({
  uri: MONGODB_URI,
  collection: 'sessions'
});

app.use(
  session({
    secret: 'my secret',
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false,
    store: store
  })
);

app.post('/uploadLogin', (req,res,next) => {
    const password = req.body.password;
    User.findOne({name:'users'})
    .then(r => {
      return bcrypt.compare(password, r.password)
      .then(doMatch => {
        console.log(doMatch);
        if(doMatch) {
          req.session.isLoggedIn = true;
          req.session.user = r;
          return req.session.save(err => {
            console.log(err);
            req.flash('success', 'You successfully logged in');
            res.redirect('/appointments');
          })
        } else {
          console.log('intra aici');
          req.flash('error', 'Please provide the right credentials');
          res.redirect('/');
        }
      })
    })



})


app.use('/404', (req,res,next) => {
  res.render('404', {
    pageTitle:'24/7 SHARED KITCHEN | 404',
    path:'/404',

  });
})
app.use('/stationone', (req,res,next) => {
    res.render('stationone', {
        pageTitle:'24/7 SHARED KITCHEN | APPOINTMENTS HOME',
        path:'/stationone',

      });
})
app.use('/stationtwo', (req,res,next) => {
    res.render('stationtwo', {
        pageTitle:'24/7 SHARED KITCHEN | APPOINTMENTS HOME',
        path:'/stationtwo',

      });
})

app.use('/stationthree', (req,res,next) => {
    res.render('stationthree', {
        pageTitle:'24/7 SHARED KITCHEN | APPOINTMENTS HOME',
        path:'/stationthree',

      });
})
app.use('/ovena', (req,res,next) => {
    res.render('ovena', {
        pageTitle:'24/7 SHARED KITCHEN | APPOINTMENTS HOME',
        path:'/ovena',

      });
})
app.use('/ovenb', (req,res,next) => {
    res.render('ovenb', {
        pageTitle:'24/7 SHARED KITCHEN | APPOINTMENTS HOME',
        path:'/ovenb',

      });
})




app.use('/appointments', (req,res,next) => {
  let message = req.flash('error');
  console.log(message);
  if(message.length > 0) {
      message = message[0];
  }
  else {
      message = null;
  }
  let message2 = req.flash('success');
  console.log(message2);
  if(message2.length > 0) {
      message2 = message2[0];
  }
  else {
      message2 = null;
  }

    res.render('appointments', {
        pageTitle:'24/7 SHARED KITCHEN | APPOINTMENTS HOME',
        path:'/appointments',
        errorMessage: message,
        succesMessage:message2

      });
})
app.use('/', (req,res,next)=> {
  let message = req.flash('error');
  console.log(message);
  if(message.length > 0) {
      message = message[0];
  }
  else {
      message = null;
  }
  let message2 = req.flash('success');
  console.log(message2);
  if(message2.length > 0) {
      message2 = message2[0];
  }
  else {
      message2 = null;
  }

    res.render('index', {
        pageTitle:'24/7 SHARED KITCHEN | APPOINTMENTS HOME',
        path:'/',
        errorMessage: message,
        succesMessage:message2
      });
})


mongoose.connect(MONGODB_URI)
.then(result => {
  app.listen(process.env.PORT || 80);
})
```

And this is the main app

Comment: Did you add engines section in your packages.json with the node version of your local machine? Like   "engines": {
    "node": "10.16.3"
  },

Comment: Hey, Problem is not with node modules, you have got a problem here loading this `'./options/SchemaTypeOptions'` module. Check if is available to given path.

Comment: Also, could you paste out code for that module? It will help us to identify whether the module  is correctly imported

Comment: make sure that your app first loaded file (app.js, server.js, .. etc) is in the same directory level as node_modules folder. It can not be in other folders.

Comment: I do have engines added, and app is loaded in the same directory, I added an edit with the code